# django tutorial poll app, trying to understand logic

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm trying to understand the logic of linking foreign keys to primary keys, so far everything seems pretty straight forward except this one part which is throwing me off, if anyone can clarify that I would really appreciate it

So this first portion I would be linking the row with primary key 1 to the variable q

```
>>> q = Question.objects.get(pk=1)


>>> q.choice_set.all()
<QuerySet []>
```

Basically Creating choices and linking them to q (which consists of the question associated to primary key 1)

```
# Create three choices.
>>> q.choice_set.create(choice_text='Not much', votes=0)
<Choice: Not much>
>>> q.choice_set.create(choice_text='The sky', votes=0)
<Choice: The sky>
```

This is the part thats throwing me OFF! Why do I have to all of a sudden on the last choice set it the variable c?

```
>>> c = q.choice_set.create(choice_text='Just hacking again', votes=0)

# Choice objects have API access to their related Question objects.
```

I see that the question is set inside of variable c, but what was the point, is there a specific reason that the last choice had to be set to a new variable c??

Is this conventional? and what i'm trying to ask is.. Everytime I create some type of foreign key relationship does my child entity (in this case choice) be linked to a new variable at the end (c in this case), and what is the significance of that?

```
>>> c.question
<Question: What's up?>

# And vice versa: Question objects get access to Choice objects.
>>> q.choice_set.all()
<QuerySet [<Choice: Not much>, <Choice: The sky>, <Choice: Just hacking again>]>
>>> q.choice_set.count()
```

I tried looking through the documentation on the reasoning and can't find anything

Comment: options are all being added to a table referenced in the variable q and then you are doing both a query & adding another option when you set it equal to c

Comment: Can you dumb that down a little more i'm sorry :( i still don't understand what you mean by that

Comment: A reason to assign the result from `create()` to a variable if you want to perform some more operations on that model instance just after you create it. In the tutorial, they just assign it to `c` to demonstrate that the Choice object has a `question` property which returns a Question object. They also show that `c` has a `delete()` method.

Comment: In any case, the data is persisted in the database. The variable name `c` is just a temporary python object that can be used as a convenient interface to the underlying database row.

Comment: So they are basically just showing you that you have choice objects linked to your question object?

Comment: sure - essentially with the first two actions you will only add records to your database tables. then, where c = you'll be adding another record and getting all the other records to associate with the variable c. That's why you can get the options from c using c.choice_set i think. hopefully that helps - let me know as I can rewrite.

Comment: choice_set <== only works when a foreignkey is set to that class right? I think I'm finally getting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an object, you do not have to assign it a variable. It is just convenient if you intend on using the created object.

```
object = Model.objects.create(parameters)
```

And

```
Model.objects.create(parameters)
object = Model.objects.get(parameters)
```

Are the same. `ForeignKey` is just another parameter (or `field`) stored when the object is created.

A `ForeignKey` field stores a reference to an object in another `Model`. When they call `c.question`, it returns the `question` object referenced in the `choice`'s `ForeignKey` field. The `__str__` method of the `Question` object is the text that you see.

Comment: Wait so basically, when i do "c.question" <--- .question isn't a method but is checking if the foreign key is linked from choice to a question?? is that right?

Comment: Updated answer @davidyeritsyan